# Pass array to a view using query string MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a multiple roles and I need to pass those roles to a another view via Return RedirectTo Action method,

My Code

```
string[] roles = new string[] { "Admin", "Supervisor", "Interviewer" };
if (roles.Count() > 1)
{
    return RedirectToAction("LoginAs","Admin",new{@roles = roles});
}
```

When I pass like this in the LoginAs view shows me Url like this,

```
http://localhost:33883/Admin/LoginAs?roles=System.String[]
```

But there's no passed values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1 :**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string[] roles = new string[] { "Admin", "Supervisor", "Interviewer" };
        var routeParameters = new RouteValueDictionary();
        for (int i = 0; i < roles.Length; i++)
        {
            routeParameters["roles[" + i + "]"] = roles[i];
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Test", "Student", routeParameters);
    }

    public ActionResult Test(string[] roles)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Output -

[image]

**Option 2:** 
Use `TempData`

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string[] roles = new string[] { "Admin", "Supervisor", "Interviewer" };
        TempData["data"] = roles;
        return RedirectToAction("Test", "Student");
    }

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        string[] roles = (string[])TempData["data"];
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Output -

[image]

**Option 3 :** 
Use `Session`

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string[] roles = new string[] { "Admin", "Supervisor", "Interviewer" };
        Session["data"] = roles;
        return RedirectToAction("Test", "Student");
    }

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        string[] roles = (string[])Session["data"];
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Output -

[image]

Comment: Thanks.What a awesome answer.I used 1st method.

Comment: In the option 1 when i use it, then my URL shows me the rols linst. like : http://localhost:33883/Home/LoginAs?roles[0]=Admin&roles[1]=Supervisor&roles[2]=Interviewer  , How to avoid that?

Comment: I dont think you can avoid that, thats why i provided Option 2,3.